# Click event in DTM doesn't always fire?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have defined and event based rule in Adobe DTM but I can see this behavior on the site that sometimes the on-click tag does not fire on the click event, where the rule is defined.

Can someone help me understand this, why this is happening and what is way out of this ?

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: In your javascript console, type _satellite.setDebug(true) and you'll be able see wether or not the click event is happening. If you are navigating to a new page, make sure you set the console to preserve previous logs.

Comment: You need to provide more details.  But offhand my guess is that when you say "sometimes" it works and "sometimes" it doesn't, it's probably working for some links but not others.  My guess is you probably have an issue with event bubbling/propagation. e.g. you have other code attached to certain links that is stopping propagation/bubbling so that other code attached to it (e.g. DTM) can't do its thing

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a DTM rule to only trigger on certain pages or some other condition that's affecting it.  Again, you need to provide more details, such as what the DTM rule(s) are, details about what's being clicked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other answers that event propagation (e.g. event.preventDefault()) is probably why it happens. But I wonder how to solve the issue when you can not let the event propagate.

My best solution is to manually capture all click events of your site and call a Direct Rule using _satellite.track(). It is far from optimal but it is effective.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Often you can use:
jQuery('body').on('click','#selector',function(){
  _satellite.track('direct call rule');
});

Worst case, if other scripts on the page are not even letting you manually track clicks, which I've seen happen, then you have to base your rule conditions on something else that happens as a result of the click, like a success message appearing. Since "enters viewport" isn't even always reliable, I sometimes have to use setInterval() to keep checking if it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some other code is preventing the click event from being emitted to the DTM code.  This will happen if other click handler code uses the preventDefault() functionality or return false, which keeps the event from triggering any other listeners.

Comment: "return false" takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM whereas preventDefault() does NOT stop the bubbling.